# uNet rigidbody movement latency issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

I am making a Multiplayer FPS using [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLPV2KyIb3jR5PhGqsO7G4PsbEC_Al-kPZ) tutorial by Brackeys  and am using a rigidbody for Player movement.

If i move forwards on computer 1, then there is about a half second delay until the player stops on computer 2.

I don't know if this is normal or if it stops when you start using paid servers.

Thanks.

Comment: can you share your code and the video of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play around with linear drag and drag on your player's rigidbody and see what fits your needs. Usually 999 linear drag and 1-5 drag does the job for me. Also, you should change physics material on your player's collider according to current state - if he is moving set it to zero friction, and when he is not moving - switch to max friction.

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear about this before - the Player will stop instantly without drag, but it won't do that until a half second after the user releases the key

Comment: You can check for Input in your Update/Fixed Update and if there's none set rigidbody velocity to 0, but this isn't really the best approach since other rigidbodies can't for example push your player.

Comment: Thanks! This works fine for my needs, and i will work on a more advanced logical process to tell it when to set the velocity to zero. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

For the player you should use a [CharacterController](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html) instead.

For that very reason.

> The traditional Doom-style first person controls are not physically
>   realistic. The character runs 90 miles per hour, comes to a halt
>   immediately and turns on a dime. Because it is so unrealistic, use of
>   Rigidbodies and physics to create this behavior is impractical and
>   will feel wrong. The solution is the specialized Character Controller.
>   It is simply a capsule shaped Collider which can be told to move in
>   some direction from a script. The Controller will then carry out the
>   movement but be constrained by collisions. It will slide along walls,
>   walk up stairs (if they are lower than the Step Offset) and walk on
>   slopes within the Slope Limit.
>
> The Controller does not react to forces on its own and it does not
>   automatically push Rigidbodies away.